# Visual Studio 2010 Workflow creation failure

Tags: workflow, visual-studio

I'm adding na new item do my sharepoint project. It is a sequential workflow, wizard appears and after a screen where he asks about type of workflow List Workflow / Site Workflow it disappears, no error, no new item in project.
When I do it the same in the new installed site (new sharepoint foundation installation) it is ok.